# Cake php 4 saving data with Associations from array

Tags: arrays, cakephp, orm, save, associations

I am trying to save data with associations from array
I have tried to follow an example from
https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html, Converting HasMany Data

```
$data = [
    'title' => 'My Title',
    'body' => 'The text',
    'comments' => [
        ['id' => 1, 'comment' => 'Update the first comment'],
        ['id' => 2, 'comment' => 'Update the second comment'],
        ['comment' => 'Create a new comment'],
    ],
];
```

I cannot find a working example.
I have 2 tables users and addresses as defined in
https://github.com/uvauser/test

When I try following in any controller action:

```
      $this->loadModel('Users');
      $data = [
         'email' => 'test@test.nl',  
        'password' => 'Tdsaw3cds32',  
        'Addresses' => [  
            [
                'street' => 'My Street',  
                'house_number' => 23,  
                'postal_code' => '1234ab',  
                'city' => 'My City',  
                'country' => 'My Country'  
             ]
        ],
    ];  

    // Trial 1
    $user1 = $this->Users->newEntity($data, [  
       'associated' => ['Addresses' =>['validate'=>false]]
    ]);  
    $this->Users->save($user1);
   
     // Trial 2
    $user2 = $this->Users->newEmptyEntity();
    $entity = $this->Users->patchEntity($user2, $data, [
        'associated' => ['Addresses' =>['validate'=>false]]
    ]);
    $this->Users->save($user2);
```

It does not save.
Can somebody give me a full working example

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description, please be more specific when describing problems and explain what _exactly_ is happening, and what _exactly_ you expect to happen instead, for example the user data might get saved, but the addresses do not.

Answer (score 1):

First, change 'Addresses' to lowercase 'addresses':

```
$data = [
         'email' => 'test@test.nl',  
        'password' => 'Tdsaw3cds32',  
        'addresses' => [ // <-------------
```

Then:

https://github.com/uvauser/test/blob/main/Model/Entity/User.php

```
 /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        'email' => true,
        'password' => true,
        'created' => true,
        'modified' => true,
        'addresses' => true, // <---------- Add Addresses to $_accessible array
    ];
```

Always try to use the debug function to detect the problem, eg:

```
debug($user1);
```

**read more:**

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment